# Why 'width: 100vw' CSS rule causes scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I try to have a top banner that **matches the screen size**. This banner contains the title + a wave SVG.
I have **exactly the result I want with these CSS rules**, the SVG matches well in responsive, **except for a scrollbar** that navigates over a few pixels (I tried many other things, including percentage widths).

**EDIT** : I need the `width:100vw` rule because I want this container to be full-width while the parent elements are not full-width.

```css
.shape-divider {
  /* It is this class which causes the scrollbar */
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

.shape-divider svg {
  display: block;
  height: 62px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-divider">
  <div class="shape-divider__top">
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p class="post__date">11/30/2022</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
            </svg>
</div>
```

Rendering :

[image: Top banner scrollbar issue]

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Why 'width: 100vw' CSS rule makes a scrollbar appear ?

Comment: It's this: `calc(100% + 1.3px);` not `100vh` ,

Comment: Changing this rule to 'width: 100%' does not correct the problem. Even when applying 'width:100%' to the parent.

Comment: Methinks you need to learn about `box-sizing`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing - by default `width:` refers to the (inner) content-width of an element's box, not its actual/total width.

Comment: Posted an answer with a working snippet, if the problem continues, upload the full code

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have a vertical scrollbar.
See this for reference : https://sbx.webflow.io/100vw-scrollbars

Use `width: 100%;` instead (works perfectly for me with the html you gived).

Here the full edited CSS :

```
.shape-divider {
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: -50%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.shape-divider svg {
    display: block;
    height: 62px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I need a solution with 'width:100vw' because I want this container to be full width when it is in a smaller width container. I'm gonna add this to the topic.

Comment: @HugoDerre you can refactor your html to have your full width div outside the small width container or you can `addoverflow-x: hidden;` to your body element

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `+ 1.3px`:

```css
.shape-divider {
  /* It is this class which causes the scrollbar */
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

.shape-divider svg {
  display: block;
  height: 62px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-divider">
  <div class="shape-divider__top">
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p class="post__date">11/30/2022</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
            </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the +1.3px with my old rules was not the fix, but i had to change .shape-divider rules by 
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
And remove the +1.3px
Now it works thanks